# Something breaking - WPF + DependancyProperties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to modify a dual handle slider to a generalised double model.

[UPDATED]: XAML Code:

```
<Slider x:Name="LowerSlider" DataContext="this" Template="{StaticResource simpleSlider}" Margin="10,0,0,0"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsUpperSliderEnabled}"                  
            Minimum="{Binding Path=Minimum}"
            Maximum="{Binding Path=Maximum}"
            Value="{Binding Path=LowerValue}"                
            SmallChange="{Binding Path=SmallChange}" 
            LargeChange="{Binding Path=LargeChange}" />
    <Slider x:Name="UpperSlider" DataContext="this" Template="{StaticResource simpleSlider}" Margin="10,0,0,0"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsUpperSliderEnabled}"                  
            Minimum="{Binding Path=Minimum}"
            Maximum="{Binding Path=Maximum}"
            Value="{Binding Path=UpperValue}"                
            SmallChange="{Binding Path=SmallChange}" 
            LargeChange="{Binding Path=LargeChange}" />
```

C# code-behind:

```
 #region Dependency Property - Minimum
    public Double Minimum
    {
        get { return (Double)GetValue(MinimumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(Double), typeof(DualHandleSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));
    #endregion

    #region Dependency Property - Lower Value
    public Double LowerValue
    {
        get { return (Double)GetValue(LowerValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LowerValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LowerValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LowerValue", typeof(Double), typeof(DualHandleSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));
    #endregion

    #region Dependency Property - Upper Value
    public Double UpperValue
    {
        get { return (Double)GetValue(UpperValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UpperValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UpperValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("UpperValue", typeof(Double), typeof(DualHandleSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(5.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnUpperValueChanged)));

    public static void OnUpperValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    #endregion

    #region Dependency Property - Maximum
    public Double Maximum
    {
        get { return (Double)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(Double), typeof(DualHandleSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(10.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMaximumChanged)));

    public static void OnMaximumChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DualHandleSlider slider = (DualHandleSlider)d;

        if (slider.IsUpperValueLockedToMax)
        {
            slider.UpperValue = (Double)e.NewValue;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Dependency Property - Small Change
    public double SmallChange
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(SmallChangeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SmallChangeProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SmallChange.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SmallChangeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SmallChange", typeof(double), typeof(DualHandleSlider),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(1.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSmallChangePropertyChanged)));

    protected static void OnSmallChangePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.NewValue);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Dependency Property - Large Change

    public double LargeChange
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(LargeChangeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LargeChangeProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LargeChange.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LargeChangeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LargeChange", typeof(double), typeof(DualHandleSlider),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(1.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnLargeChangePropertyChanged)));

    protected static void OnLargeChangePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.NewValue);
    }
    #endregion
```

The problem is, the control does not react in any way to properties set when the control is implemented. Even programmatically editing the properties does not work? I figure it's a stupid mistake, but I've been pouring over this code for a while now. Any ideas?

EDIT: Still no luck! Nothing in output about binding errors.

[image: Odd behaviour!]

Comment: Is `root` the name of the `UserControl`? And is there any reason why Value is using a OneWay binding?

Comment: No it's not, and I overlooked that earlier; like I mentioned I'm adapting 3rd party code

Comment: The first version with `ElementName=root` looked fine, you just need to name your `UserControl` to `root`.

Comment: That worked! At least for minimum and maximum! Just got to clean up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close with your initial code prior to the latest edit. The key is to name your *user control* and to bind against the *user control*. This allows the `DataContext` to flow through naturally if you ever support embedded `ContentControl`s. Setting `DataContext="this"` literally sets your data context to the *string* `"this"`.

Instead add something like `x:Name="ThisControl"` to your `<UserControl...` line and then update the bindings to point to `ElementName=ThisControl`. Make sure the `Slider.Value` bindings are `Mode=TwoWay` (which is the default if you don't specify a mode):

```
<UserControl x:Class="NameSpace.ThisControl"
             x:Name="ThisControl">
<Grid>
    <Slider x:Name="LowerSlider"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsUpperSliderEnabled, ElementName=ThisControl}"
            Minimum="{Binding Minimum, ElementName=ThisControl}"
            Maximum="{Binding Maximum, ElementName=ThisControl}"
            Value="{Binding LowerValue, ElementName=ThisControl}"
            SmallChange="{Binding SmallChange, ElementName=ThisControl}"
            LargeChange="{Binding LargeChange, ElementName=ThisControl}" />
    <Slider x:Name="UpperSlider"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsUpperSliderEnabled, ElementName=ThisControl}"  
            Minimum="{Binding Minimum, ElementName=ThisControl}"
            Maximum="{Binding Maximum, ElementName=ThisControl}"
            Value="{Binding UpperValue, ElementName=ThisControl}"
            SmallChange="{Binding SmallChange, ElementName=ThisControl}" 
            LargeChange="{Binding LargeChange, ElementName=ThisControl}" />
```

Comment: Yeah I've got it :) Just got to investigate snappy kind of sliders

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the control DataContext property to the right value? You can see the output window to see the Binding errors you may have.

EDIT: Using ElementName=root you're directing your binding to something called root. The normal way of doing this (IMHO) is to delete the ElementName part of all the bindings and setting the DataContext = this to be able to bind to its own DP.

Comment: The OP is using `ElementName` for each data binding, therefore `DataContext` will be irrelevant for those.

Comment: Building...slowly...(Pentium 4)

Comment: It's a best practice to *not* change the `DataContext` of a `UserControl` or `Control` and instead bind against the control itself. This way if you end up embedding a `ContentControl` or `ItemsControl`, any template with bindings will work properly.